# Allowing external access to node.js application while hosting through XAMPP

Tags: node.js, xampp, portforwarding

So I have the following URL that leads external users to my port-forwarded XAMPP website.

`http://ip_to_my_computer:433`

However, my node server is on port `466`. How do I connect to it? I can't do

```
var client = io.connect('http://ip_to_my_computer:433:466');
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to connect to your web server from Node? Or you want to connect to your Node server from XAMPP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to initiate a client request *from* your XAMPP hosted server (like a .php or .js script) *to* your Node.js instance?

Simply:

```
var client = io.connect('http://ip_to_my_computer:node_server_port');
```

And in your case, you claim your Node server is running on port 466.

I'd bet though that your OS will block a port that low - try changing your Node server to listen on a port between 8000 - 9000.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The Node.js instance and XAMPP server are the same computer. But when I try your suggestion, I always get an ERR_TIMED_OUT. But if I just set it to `http://localhost:466`, it will load for me, but not any external visitors.

Comment: Can you get to your Node server in your browser by IP:466?

Comment: I cannot. However, `localhost:466` does work (as opposed to `ip_to_my_computer:466` in the browser.

Comment: That's assuredly an OS problem then. It's probably blocking the port. Try a higher port that isn't normally blocked, like something between 8000 and 9000.